# Elasticsearch range query not working with match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to combine match query and range query but its not working properly.

```
GET file*/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "message":"timeout"
               }
            },
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "message":"java.lang.IllegalStateException"
               }
            },
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "@timestamp":{  
                     "gt":"now-1h",
                     "lte":"now",
                     "time_zone":"+01:00"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Date filter is not working properly here ,am i doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace **},** with **],** and add **filter** to query. For example:

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "should": [
        { "match":{ "message":"timeout" }},
        { "match":{ "message":"java.lang.IllegalStateException"}}  
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { "range": { "@timestamp": { "gt": "now-15m", "lte": "now", "time_zone":"+01:00" }}} 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```